# Best Practices for implementing Chat in Django (storing online users)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, django, chat

I'm implementing a chat system in Django.

I'm having a bit of trouble deciding how to create the models which decide who are the online users. Two problems I see:

1. you can't really tell when a user goes offline
2. I want the "users" to be lightweight (no log-in necessary), which means I don't want to use Django's user system.

Any suggestions on how to go about modeling this?

Answer (score 1):

Store this info in your cache. It's ephemeral enough that it doesn't belong in a long-term database, and access needs to be REALLY fast.

You don't need to store a lot of info to deal with a chat session, so storing it in the user's session (you can do this with anonymous non-logged in users, and then pull info from the "real" users table if they happen to be logged in) is the right way to go provided you're using the pure caching session backend and something like memcached.

Comment: I'm not too familiar with the caching backend. Will it let me store this kind of information and access it from different sessions? I can't just save it in one user's session, since all users need to be "aware" of who is online.

Comment: For the overall information, store it directly in the cache. For information specific to an individual user (like chat preferences), store it in the users session.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Pail McMillan's answer that using a cache would be the right approach. In the past I have used [Django's low level caching API](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/cache/#the-low-level-cache-api) which simply allows you to store key value pairs centrally.

I am not sure how efficient this would be but you could very simply store a comma separated string of the IDs of the users which are currently online:

```
from django.core.cache import cache

cache.set('users-online', '4,6,12,34')
```

and then:

```
for user_id in cache.get('users-online').split(','):
    user = User.objects.get(pk=user_id)
    # do something with the user ...
```

Comment: You don't even need to do that. You can store any pickleable object directly - the cache api takes care of it for you.

Comment: and that would be pretty inefficient, because it would trigger a separate query for each user who is online. Much better to store whatever info is necessary in the cache and update that when users log in.

Comment: Right, point being though that you can store stuff in the cache via this interface.